# How does a U.S. citizen move from the United States without a passport?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, passport

I'm a U.S citizen who can't obtain a U.S. passport.
I want to move to Panama (prepared to give up us citizenship) and obtain a Panamanian passport to move about freely. I have employment opportunities and am financially sound.

How is this done?

Comment: Pay your bills!

Comment: We'd need to know why you can't obtain a U.S. passport. I suspect though that you would not be able to enter Panama without a passport no matter what the reasons are. @LorenPechtel, we don't know why he can't obtain a passport. The OP might be very conscientious about 'paying their bills'.

Comment: Do you have (or can obtain) another country's nationality? If so, you can travel on that country's passport.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the only way to do this is illegally. The discussion of illegal activities is frowned upon.

(I am not trying to be judgmental, I only mean that the reasons why a citizen of the US can't get a US passport are generally because the authorities do not want the person to leave. Therefore, the person wishing to leave can only do so against the wishes of the authorities - which means doing it illegally)

Comment: Another option is to get asylum, but that assumes a legitimate asylum claim, which is unlikely for someone from the US. If asylum is granted, the person is immune from prosecution for immigration violations committed in reaching the country granting asylum.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the only grounds for asylum to be granted are if one's life would otherwise be in danger. Because of the strong rule of law in the US, as well as its generally transparent legal system, I don't see how that criterion could reasonably be met.

Comment: You're wrong:  Fear of persecution can be the basis of an asylum claim; it need not rise to the level of fear for one's life.  But you're also right, of course:  It's highly unlikely for a US citizen to have a viable claim.

Comment: You might want to add that Panama and the US have an extradition treaty. Panama, of late, avoids the lengthy process by simply deporting the individual if they're in Panama illegally. Using a fake passport is included, and for that, Panama immediately deports.

Comment: "the reasons why a citizen of the US can't get a US passport are generally because the authorities do not want the person to leave" Or if the person has back child support or back taxes, or if the person hasn't paid expenses incurred for a return from a foreign country at government expense.